# Problema con area de enlace

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

he intentado arreglar el area que me queda a los lados del enlace cuando defino los grid layout, puedo tocar el boton desde cada esquina, y quiero se adapte esa area al tamaño de la palabra continuar, cuando intento con max width, se me pone en una esquina y se arregla, pero necesito que quede en el centro y ajustado a su correspondiente tamaño

```
css:  
.next__index {
    grid-area: next;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--colorprincipal);
}

html:
    <a class='btn__volver'href="../index.html">Página anterior</a>
```